# Sumproduct VBA instead of formula

Tags: excel, vba

The following problem has been bothering me for quite a while.

I use the following formula to rank Revenues (in range B2:B10) conditional on Years (in range A2:A10):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=A10)*($B$2:$B$10>B10))+1`

I paste this formula in Range(C2:C10) to find the rank for each observation.

This all works fine, however, here's the catch: I need to do this not for 10 observations, but for 124440 observations; running this paralyzes my Workbook for an inordinate amount of time.

So my question is: could you help me to find a way, that allows me to calculate the above mentioned formula without having to copy/paste it in each cell (probably by using VBA), which in turn will allow the computations to run much faster?

I have scoured the web but, since I am a VBA newbie, I haven't got a clue what I should be looking for

```
Company Name               Year - Fiscal    Revenues    Rank
AAR CORP                   2003             150         1
AAR CORP                   2004             180         1
AAR CORP                   2005             120         2
ADC TELECOMMUNICATIONS INC 2003             90          3
ADC TELECOMMUNICATIONS INC 2004             99          3
ADC TELECOMMUNICATIONS INC 2005             108         3
AFP IMAGING CORP           2003             120         2
AFP IMAGING CORP           2004             130         2
AFP IMAGING CORP           2005             140         1
```

As per your request. Instead of 10 observations think 124440.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` runs in at least ¹⁄₃ of the calculation load and processing time of an equivalent `SUMPRODUCT`. If you have Excel 2007 or later, try `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$124440, A10, $B$2:$B$124440, ">="&B10)`. see [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-f379e763-b946-49d3-822a-d197cf786683)

Comment: can you post a sample output? Just the 10 lines with revenues, dates and result of the formula.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thanks for the feedback! It definitely is a huge step in the right direction but I still need to wait for like 5-10 minutes before its finished. Is there another huge speed gain when I use this with VBA? Or is this approximately as fast as its going to get?

Comment: I don't think many here are going to want to write your code from scratch if you want a solution in VBA. Try a Google search for examples first. In the meantime, you may get a small speed boost by concatenating the values in column A and B in column C (    =A2&"-"&B2) then doing a countif on the single column in column D (    =COUNTIF($C$2:$C$124440,C2))

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: How could I post that info? I am not yet allowed to post images or attachments given my low rep. Tried to just post the data in the comment box, doesn't translate.

Comment: Aren't the years in col A? Are they grouped by year (i.e. sorted)? If so your formula wouldn't necessarily need to refer to the whole range

Comment: @Hieronymus5, just edit your question and add manually some rows with the inputs and outputs, so we're able to understand the objective and lead you to the right approach

Comment: @Dave: I fully understand, I just got some basic knowledge by watching youtube videos and indeed, google, but this only gives me insight to some extent. I shall try your suggestion. Thanks everyone for their input by the way

Comment: If you sorted the data with `Key1:=Columns("A"), Key2:=Columns("B")` you could adjust the formula so that it didn't have to look at the entire column for each `COUNTIFS`. But more directly to your question... no, there is not *magic bullet* that will reduce the calculations that need to take place. You might want to save the workbook as a binary `.XLSB` to see if that improved things. At a minimum it will reduce the size.

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks again, I'll try doing that. Who was talking about a magic bullet? I merely want to know whether there is something I can do on my part to make the computations run faster. For example, whether using something like 'Application.Countif(Rng1,A10,Rng2, ">="&B10) would work/speed things up. Just trying to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I would approach the problem without writing any code nor formula (the time you spend for writing a sorting function such this one in VBA would just be longer than due):

1) Sort all your data by the column containing the year, so you will easily distinguish the companies results every year; 

2) For every year (you will easily see the year into the "Year - Fiscal" column since now the data are sorted), execute a sorting "larger to smaller" on the column "Revenues".

Comment: You now have a list from the best to the worst company for every year, there you will just have to start by "1" on the best company and going forward. 
This should take a few seconds (Excel sorting runs within instants over hundrends of thousands data) and your spreadsheet will be clean from formulas that will call the calculations everytime you touch something, so making unreadable (or almost) from the final reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how many of you still follow this post. But for full disclosure, this is exactly what I was looking for and is much faster (gets the job done for 124000 obs in 2 min instead of 15):

```
Sub Rank()

    Dim LastRow         As Long
    Dim LastCol         As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        LastCol = .Columns.Count + .Columns(1).Column - 1
    End With

    'Create a temporary column so that it can be used to re-sort data to its original state
    Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Value = 1
    Cells(3, LastCol + 1).Value = 2
    Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Resize(2).AutoFill Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))

    'Sort the data by Column B, in ascending order
    Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)).Sort key1:=Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, ordercustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    'Select B2 prior to creating a dynamic named range, since it uses relative references
    Range("B2").Select

    'Create the dynamic named range
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "MyDynRng", "=INDEX(R2C2:R" & LastRow & "C2,MATCH(RC2,R2C2:R" & _
        LastRow & "C2,0)):INDEX(R2C6:R" & LastRow & "C6,MATCH(RC2,R2C2:R" & LastRow & "C2,1))"

    'Put the header for the ranking column
    Cells(1, LastCol + 2).Value = "Rank"

    'Enter the ranking formula and convert them to values
    With Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 2))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(INDEX(MyDynRng,0,1),RC2,INDEX(MyDynRng,0,5),"">""&RC6)+1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Re-sort the data to its original state
    Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 2)).Sort key1:=Cells(1, LastCol + 1), order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, ordercustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    'Delete the defined name
    ThisWorkbook.Names("MyDynRng").Delete

    'Delete the temporary column
    Cells(1, LastCol + 1).EntireColumn.Delete

    'To change the Lookup Column, adjust column numbers in the dynamic range (For example C5 to C6 if you want to go from column E to F

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

This got suggested to me by a guy called Domenic. Don't know if hes active on Stackoverflow but if he is, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VBA solution but an alternative formula.

With

ColumnA as **CompanyName**,
ColumnB as **Year**,
ColumnC as **Revenue**,
ColumnD as **Rank**

First, sort the data

1. by the Year (column B)
2. and then by the Revenue (column C)

On the Rank column,

1. for the first row of data, key in 1 as the rank.
2. for the second row of data, key in this formula:
   `=IF(B3=B2,D2 + 1, 1)`

The formula is saying that:

`if the year is the same`
`increase the rank number by 1`
`else`
`reset the rank as 1`

Drag the formula down.

The formula calculates pretty quickly I think but in order to retain the assigned Ranks, you'd need copy and Paste Special, only the Values, to replace the formula with a value. This way should you decide to sort the whole table, you wont loose the Ranks